# Listar arquivo excluindo primeira letra

Tags: linux, shell-script

Eu tenho um arquivo chamado `1arquivo` e listo ele normalmente com o comando `ls`. Como posso usar o ls excluindo a primeira letra para que me retorne apenas `arquivo`. Tem que ser uma solução genérica pois terei vários arquivos nesta mesma situação.

Comment: sua pergunta foi respondida?

Answer (score 3):

utilizando cut seu comando ficaria assim:

```
ls ?arquivo | cut -c2-80
```

utilizando comando awk fica assim:

```
ls ?arquivo | awk '{ print substr($0,2,length($0)); }'
```

Só para níveis didáticos: utilizando expressão regular isso `?` equivale a qualquer caractere ou seja ?arquivo pode ser (1arquivo,2arquivo,3arquivo), e esse código `*` equivale a qualquer coisa ou seja (1arquivo, julioarquivo, 09999arquivo).

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: `ls | cut -c 2-`